# Android Create/Write File in Internal Storage

Tags: android, internal-storage

I have been looking all over on how to create a file and then write to it in internal storage for a couple days now and can't find anything that works or that I can understand. I have never done anything like this before so I'm pretty lost.

According to the android developer website page, this code should create a folder if it does not exist, but when I call it, it gives me an error. The class extends SurfaceView if that means anything.

```
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {

        }

    });

    createFile();

}

public void createFile() {
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = getContext().openFileOutput(FILENAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All I want to be able to do in the end is create a file in internal storage, save an integer (my players score that's in the game) to that file, and then be able to load and save this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get an error? Can you paste your logcat?

Comment: If you would like to implement persistent key value pairs, I would suggest [Android's SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Sorry, took a little while.
 "08-27 15:10:46.005: E/Trace(737): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)", <--That's the only error that comes up in red in my log cat

Comment: Isn't the file name mentioned in the error description? Use 'context' prameter instead of 'getContext()'.

Comment: 'this code should create a folder if it does not exist,'. No. It will create a file. And delete one if it already exists.

Comment: @greenapps, I do not think it is accurate to say the code would delete the file if it exists. It would truncate the file before writing.

Comment: Sorry for not being accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to implement persistent key value pairs,  I would  suggest [Android's SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Using `SharedPreferences` is as easy as:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); //MY_PREFS_NAME could  be something useful, like username, so your data can be easily separated.

final static SCORE = "score"; //This variable simply holds the string "score", so we can tell the SharedPreferences which data we'd like.
int getScore() {
    return prefs.getInt(SCORE, 0); // second argument is default value if there is no value for key.
}

void setScore(int score) {
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(SCORE, score);
    editor.commit();
}
```

These settings will persist over multiple runs of your application.

Comment: Hm, I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I write and read photo files locally. A similar process can be applied for handling different types of files. Just use a different file extension and a different method return data-type.

```
// Creates an ImageFile
private File createNewPhotoFile() throws IOException {

    String imageFileName = "JPEG";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();

    image.createNewFile();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(image);
    fo.write(stream.toByteArray());
    fo.close();

    return image;
}

// Retrieve and convert from file to Bitmap
private Bitmap retrieveImageFromFile(ImageView target, File fileForPath) {

    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = target.getWidth();
    int targetH = target.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileForPath.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = 4; //Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newPhotoFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

    return bitmap;
}
```